# How to retrieve Stripe payment in Blazor Server app?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, blazor, blazor-server-side

To accept online payments from Stripe into my Blazor server app I use the code below (simplified here; the complete code was retrieved from this link [here](https://github.com/bradwellsb/blazor-stripe)  )

It works well. The payment is processed (Test mode) and I can see it on my Stripe account if I go there and check the payments myself, but how can I retrieve the payment info in code from Stripe? I see that each payment has an id but how do I know what is the Id of the payment the client just entered ?

```
  private async Task CheckoutHandler(string priceId)
    {
        status = (false, "");
        formDisabled = true;
        try
        {
            string sessionId = await CreateCheckoutSessionAsync(priceId);

            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("redirectToCheckout", sessionId);
        }
        catch (Stripe.StripeException e)
        {
            status = (true, e.Message);
            formDisabled = false;
        }
    }    


  public async Task<string> CreateCheckoutSessionAsync(string priceId, string customerId = null)
    {
        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("stripe_key");

        var options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                CustomerEmail = "benac421@gmail.com",
                Customer = customerId,
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { "card", },
                LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
                {
                   new SessionLineItemOptions
                   {
                        Name = "Payment name",
                        Description = "Payment for product ",
                        Amount = Convert.ToInt32(500),
                        Currency = "usd",
                        Quantity = 1,
                    },
                },
                Mode = "payment",
                SuccessUrl = $"https://localhost:44347/success,
                CancelUrl = $"https://localhost:44347/checkout",
                ClientReferenceId = "paymentid"
            };
        try
        {
            return (await new SessionService().CreateAsync(options)).Id;

            //var service = new SessionService();
            //Session session = service.Create(options);
            //return session.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's put a bit of background first. Since you are using Checkout, you will have a [Checkout Session object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object), which contains a [PaymentIntent object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object) inside. Checkout object 's id starts with cs_test_xxx (Test mode), while PaymentIntent object's id starts with pi_xxx.

Now suppose that your client has entered a card or any other Payment Methods on your Checkout session, you will receive a webhook event called [checkout.session.completed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed). If you set up your webhook endpoint properly, you can catch the Checkout Session object there, then find the Payment Intent accordingly.

Stripe has a [comprehensive guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) on checkout.session.completed. Give it a try!